# Are there any translation memory / repositories / glossaries for Delphi Run-time?

Tags: delphi, localization, translation

I need to prepare Delphi 2007 application for localization. Now, about 80% of what needs to be translated is actually Delphi run-time library. I cannot imagine this stuff needs to be re-translated over and over again, by each developer who localizes his/hers software.

So, I'm looking where I can get "translation memory" / "glossary" for Delphi 2007 run-time, either free or for money. I'm particularly interested in Traditional Chinese.

Comment: I'm surprised that you need to translate delphi runtime text. What part of the runtime shows text to your users.

Comment: @David: I would guess exception messages like "''a'' is not a valid integer value.".

Comment: @Andreas There's hardly any of those and surely you don't show them to the user. Can't really be 80%.

Comment: @David For example the `consts` unit.

Comment: If it is what Andreas suspects, I'm sure there is a resource DLL for all common languages. But D2007 is Ansi. Better off with modern delphi.

Comment: There are all the error messages (hundreds of them), all common dialogs / components, common button names, week day names, etc. Several hundred of strings. I'd hate paying for custom translation of this, when I know for sure this was already translated, many times over and over.

Comment: @David
Delphi 2007 or Delphi 2009 doesn't matter much, as most RTL / VCL strings are the same. And whether Delphi itself is ANSI or Unicode is irrelevant to my question. I was unable to find such resource DLL for Chinese for example.

Comment: Common dialogs are localised by Windows. Button names are chosen by you. Error messages shouldn't be seen by user. But I do take your point that this stuff must be translated already. It's all implemented with `resourcestring` so it's ready for that. Something tells me that the enterprise version might have the translations available. I am very interested in the question and hope somebody knows something!!

Comment: At least in Delphi XE2 the shipped translations are only German, French and Japanese - the languages Delphi is available in. Even DxGetText doesn't have Chinese translations of the Delphi RTL.

Comment: BTW, the 80% rate doesn't mean that 80% of the runtime strings have to be translated (because most of them will never show to the user). It states only that 80% of the overall translations are runtime strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the 
[GNU Gettext for Delphi and C++ Builder](http://dxgettext.po.dk/).

This tool is able to translate all `resourcestring` defined in the exe into any language, on the fly. It is therefore able to translate the `resourcestring` used by the Delphi RTL, into any language.

AFAIK there are several [pre-made translations](http://dybdahl.dk/dxgettext/translations/) available, for several languages (more than the official French / German / Japanese / English versions).

*Update:* I used some ideas of GetText for [the i18n features of our mORMot framework](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/09/14/L10n-and-i18n-in-our-framework), for the UI part. This will use plain text files for translation, instead of .po or other proprietary systems, and is more Delphi specific (e.g. dfm content are parsed). This is dedicated to our framework (e.g. it uses its RTTI classes), but it may be a good start if you want to write your own unit, with some enhancements compared to GetText or the Delphi IDE.

Comment: GNU Gettext is enough invasive to be not a so good choice. Since Delphi own localization tool improved (but it has still issues in D2007), it is IMHO a fairly better solutions, especially when it comes to form localization, because it has a preview and can localize not only strings, you may need to adapt graphical elements to the target customers, especially when they are in countries with a very different culture and traditions.

Comment: Even if you do not (want to) use GNU Gettext for Delphi you could still use its pre-made Delphi RTL translations. Oh, and be sure to take the German translations from the dxgettext svn repository because I have improved them significantly in the last few months.

Comment: @Mad Hatter This is a matter of taste. What do you call "invasive"? That all resourcestring are translated? It's a feature, IMHO. I really don't like Delphi localization tools, for two main reasons: that you need the IDE to update a translation, and it will use libraries.

Comment: It's "invasive" because it requires code changes. You have to code for Getttext. Delphi localization tools doesn't. You don't need the whole IDE to update a translation, just the ETE executable. It uses DLLs, true, but that's how the whole Windows localization works. Windows itself and Office, for example, are localized the same way. It's simple to deploy (and to update), you may deploy only the localizations you need, and it can translate any resource, including images, videos, sounds, etc.

Comment: Obviously, the pre-made translations you mentioned are not even close to being complete, but it's the closest thing to what I was looking for in the answers, so I mark it as accepted.

P.S. Thanks for Gettext for Delphi pointer!

Comment: @Mad Hatter Which code change does it require? All resourcestring are translated on the fly, and also all forms. Some initialization code, and that's all. About deployment, it's based on external files. I think you didn't look at the exact implementation of this library. There is much more than `_('English text')` in it.

Comment: 1) Add TranslateComponent (self); to **each** form

Comment: 1) Add TranslateComponent (self); to **each** form 2) Add "typical ignores" 3) Build a complex directory structure 4) It "works better" if you use the _() syntax (very invasive) 5) It may fail with some controls, requiring calls to translateproperties(). Anyway, like all this translation libraries, it doesn't let you adjust the size of the controls to reflect the translated strings. GetText is a cheap library that works in simple applica

Answer (score 2):

Delphi itself is not translated in Chinese... but I agree, some companies/translaters have certainly already did it.

For information, within the Delphi existing languages (French, German & Japanese), there are specific files with translations in sources subfolders, for example: ...\RAD Studio\8.0\source\vcl\fr, ...\RAD Studio\9.0\source\rtl\common\de, ...

For instance, the begin of the French *Vcl.Consts.pas*:

```
{*******************************************************}
{                                                       }
{            Delphi Visual Component Library            }
{                                                       }
{ Copyright(c) 1995-2011 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. }
{                                                       }
{*******************************************************}

unit Vcl.Consts;

interface

resourcestring
  SOpenFileTitle = 'Ouvrir';
  SCantWriteResourceStreamError = 'Impossible d'#39'écrire dans un flux en lecture seule';
  SDuplicateReference = 'WriteObject appelé deux fois pour la même instance';
  SClassMismatch = 'La ressource %s est d'#39'une classe incorrecte';
  SInvalidTabIndex = 'Index d'#39'onglet hors limites';
  SInvalidTabPosition = 'Position d'#39'onglet incompatible avec le style d'#39'onglet en cours';
  SInvalidTabStyle = 'Style d'#39'onglet incompatible avec la position d'#39'onglet en cours';
  SInvalidBitmap = 'Image de bitmap non valide';
  SInvalidIcon = 'Image d'#39'icône non valide';
  SInvalidMetafile = 'MetaFichier incorrect';
  SInvalidPixelFormat = 'Format de pixel non valide';
  SInvalidImage = 'Image non valide';
  SBitmapEmpty = 'Bitmap vide';
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, as you said, it's only French/German/Japanese... So it's not really a repository, and rather limited in terms of number of languages.

Comment: and this gets tricky when you are dealing with db components which are using this resource string and expect some english text instead of a french one...

Comment: @haimg: I agree ; BTW, this is a good place to search all the strings you need to translate.

Comment: @RBA: Usually, there are tags in the code to explicitly tell to not translate these kinds of strings... do not hesitate to report the issues you found in [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?p=10)

Comment: I believe by **translation repository** OP meant literally translation repository as presented under `View -> Translation Manager -> Repository` (or ETM stand-alone tool), where messages to be localized are RTL messages. So at the moment of starting localization process (creating a resource DLL) ~80% of messages to be localized are coming from RTL, not application under localization itself, and OP is looking for reuse work done previously. @haimg, please correct me if i am under wrong impression.

Comment: @Downvoter-step-into-the-light:
You're correct. Actually, any repository format will work for me. TMX, Delphi's native XML, whatever.

Comment: @haimg, i got your question right then. I had similar head scratching when i was creating `ru-ru` resource DLL for my rather tiny software, and the volume of work with Delphi standard tool appeared to be much larger than i was planning. Unfortunately i did not find any premade translation and has to do that myself, may your luck will be better and you will find desired repository part(s), because i'm pretty sure this type of work has been done previously. Anyway, i suggest you to rephrase question a little, because going thru `resourcestrings` unit-by-unit as in answers is not Delphi way to go

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, IIRC it was Delphi 5, Borland released a [translation repository file](http://www.torry.net/docs/inprise/updates/d5tr.zip) for its own localization tool supporting some languages (but not Chinese, though). It still works and can be used as a base for adding more translations, it was a good idea, but as many good ideas in Delphi it was quickly forgotten. IMHO I would not waste time in delivering localized IDE versions, I'd use those resources to deliver a "translation repository" for the RTL/VCL, which would be much more useful.

Comment: Delphi XE2 still has the repository, although with only 3 languages (German/French/Japanese), so this was not "quickly forgotten". Alas, 3 languages only :-(

Comment: Ah, good to know they added the actual translations to the repository now. There are only three I guess because those are the languages Delphi itself is localized to. It's a pity no Delphi developers from other countries filled the gap. Unluckily community contributions in Delphi are far less than with other languages.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge this DOES NOT exist...either payed of free. You have only the French/German/Japanese versions of the vcl.consts unit. For everything you need to be translated you need to do it by yourself.